# Why won't my program recognize variables from my structure?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm trying to create a range-based loop to fill a vector of structure for a lab in one of my classes. The problem is when I write something like

```
"movieInfo.Title.push_back(tempTitle);"
```

it doesn't recognize the "Title" is a string within the structure "movie".

I've already tried to use "emplace_back" and have tried to fill the vector directly. The lab prompt is to modify a vector lab of the same theme but with vectors of structures.

My structure is as follows

```
    struct movie 
{ 
    std::string Title, Director, Genre, Year, runningTime;
};
```

and it is defined in main as

```
vector<movie> movieInfo{};
```

and finally, my "for" loop is written as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    string tempTitle, tempDirector, tempGenre, tempYear, tempTime;

    getline(inFile, tempTitle, ',');
    movieInfo.Title.push_back(tempTitle);
    getline(inFile, tempDirector, ',');
    movieInfo.Director.push_back(tempDirector);
    getline(inFile, tempGenre, ',');
    movieInfo.Genre.push_back(tempGenre);
    getline(inFile, tempYear, ',');
    movieInfo.Year.push_back(tempYear);
    getline(inFile, tempTime);
    movieInfo.runningTime.push_back(tempTime);
}
```

My error is

```
"error C2039: 'Title': is not a member of     'std::vector<movie,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=movie
1>        ]"
```

and this repeats for all of the push_back lines.

Comment: `movieInfo.Title.push_back(tempTitle);` - `Title` is a `string`, not a `vector` and `movieInfo` is a `vector`, not a `struct`/`class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the way vectors of structures works in C++. C++ won't create a vector for every field in your structure, if the vector type is a structure. The right way to do this is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    string tempTitle, tempDirector, tempGenre, tempYear, tempTime;
    movie tempMovie = {};
    getline(inFile, tempTitle, ',');
    getline(inFile, tempDirector, ',');
    getline(inFile, tempGenre, ',');
    getline(inFile, tempYear, ',');
    getline(inFile, tempTime);
    tempMovie.Title = tempTitle;
    tempMovie.Director = tempDirector;
    // And so on...
    movieInfo.push_back(tempMovie); // Push the whole struct into the struct's vector
}
```

Of course there are others ways to do the insertion part you should consider, like emplace_back..

Comment: Ah! I see what I did wrong. The book I have doesn't have a section on vectors of structures, so I was a bit confused. Thanks for your help!